# Exponentiating a multi-controlled NOT gate for trotterization

Tags: qiskit, trotterization

I am trying to exponentiate a multi-controlled NOT gate (MCX) via .exp_i() function for trotterization in Qiskit , but I cannot find such a gate represented in opflow. Is there a convenient way around it?

Answer (score 1):

[`MCXGate`](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.circuit.library.MCXGate.html) exists in Qiskit's circuit library. So, you can get the operator as follows:

```
from qiskit.circuit.library import MCXGate
from qiskit.opflow import CircuitOp

num_ctrl_qubits = 3
ctrl_state = '111' # Optionally, set the control state
gate = MCXGate(num_ctrl_qubits, ctrl_state = ctrl_state)
mcx_op = CircuitOp(gate)
```

Now, you may call `exp_i()`

```
evolution_op = mcx_op.exp_i()
```